# PowerBI: RDL -> PBIX conversion // is it possible?

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, power-bi-report-server

1. I have a RDL file written in SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services),
   can I convert it into a PBIX file (Power BI)?
2. Does the Power BI report server have the ability to support both the PBIX and RDL files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RDL and PBIX are very different and can't be automatically converted in either direction but the Power BI service (powerbi.com) supports both.